# Display table and table-cell ignoring the vertical-align middle property

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to understand as to why browsers would be ignoring the `display:table` and `table-cell`, `vertical-align:middle` property. It seems very straight forward to me but my results are completely different from what I am telling my `div`s to do using CSS. Here is a snapshot of the problem:

[image]

How can I get the box to be displayed in the very middle of the page?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid rgb(112, 112, 112);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">box</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `height:100%` to `html,body`, because otherwise `#container` will be `height:100%` of nothing.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid rgb(112, 112, 112);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">box</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** This happens across browsers **not** only in IE